# Parsing DateTime Strings with time zones for various browsers

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, cross-browser, date-format

I have been reading the many posts on this topic and have been trying the code examples but I can not seem to get my parsing to work.

I have a dijit DateTextBox on my form.  I've noticed that when used in different browsers I receive a different String reperesentation of the date time.  For example today's date in:

IE8:

```
Fri Mar 11 00:00:00 MST 2011
```

Mozilla/Chrome/Safari:

```
Thu Mar 11 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)
```

Opera:

```
Thu Mar 11 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700
```

In my code I created the following SimpleDateFormat's :

```
private final static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
private final static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)", Locale.US);
private final static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ", Locale.US);
```

I then try and parse it later like this:

```
            try {
                calcDate = dateFormat.parse(changeDate); 
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                try {                   
                    calcDate = dateFormat2.parse(changeDate);
                } catch (ParseException e2) {
                     try {
                         calcDate = dateFormat3.parse(changeDate);
                     } catch (ParseException e3) {
                         e3.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
            }
```

So far only IE8 parses correctly.  I created a few statements to output the strings before the parse and it looks like my formats match the patterns.

I even installed the joda time library and tried some of the examples like this:

```
    String currentDate = "Sun Mar 29 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0700";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ");
    DateTime myDate = formatter.parseDateTime(currentDate);
```

This gives me the error 'Invalid format..... GMT-0700 is malformed'

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after looking at this again I came up with a work around that is working on all the browsers mentioned above.

I changed my second date format to

```
private final static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy", Locale.US);
```

I then took the first 15 characters from the date string returned from the browser and parsed it like this:

```
            try {
                calcDate = dateFormat.parse(changeDate); 
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                try {
                     changeDate = changeDate.substring(0, 15);                      
                    calcDate = dateFormat2.parse(changeDate);
                } catch (ParseException e2) {
                     e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

It works like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider parsing the string representing the date in the client side. So your server knows what format it will receive, regardless of the browser's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For your second format, try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (zzzz)")
```